# Work around not being able to use non-reifiable parameters with varargs

Tags: java, android, generics, variadic-functions

There are many questions about the issue of combining generics with varargs. This would require generic arrays which don't exist when actual code tries to instantiate them. Moreover, there's a good amount of documentation on the compiler-vagueness of warnings from varargs methods with non-reifiable parameters. Because of type erasure this creates potential heap pollution, hence the warning (in Java 6 at the caller). However, my question is not about these problems themselves. I think I understand that some things aren't possible. *What I'd like to know is the way to elegantly workaround these problems in my complex case.*

Links for related topics:

- [Is it possible to solve the "A generic array of T is created for a varargs parameter" compiler warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445233/is-it-possible-to-solve-the-a-generic-array-of-t-is-created-for-a-varargs-param) where some call this situation a "bad feature" bug.
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/non-reifiable-varargs-type.html

### My case

I have a `BookItemSearchAddTask` that extends from the *Android `AsyncTask`* but somewhere along its inheritance hierarchy has been made generic, more abstract at higher levels:

At a higher level it's **`SearchAddTask`**, which contains the method **`start()`** to execute the task, called from a client that knows that it passes a `BookItem` product in.

```
public abstract class SearchAddTask<ProductToAdd extends Product & NamedProduct> 
        extends AddTask<ProductToAdd, ProductToAdd> {

    public void start(ViewActivity context, ProductToAdd product) throws SpecificAddTaskDomainException, TaskExistsException, TaskUnavailableException {
        super.start(context, product);
            //more stuff ...
            execute(product);
    }
}
```

A level lower it's an **`ItemSearchAddTask`**. Here the method **`doInBackground`** is implemented, as required by the `AsyncTask` API. It can still use generics.

```
public abstract class ItemSearchAddTask extends SearchAddTask<I> {

    public I doInBackground(I... params) {
            I product = params[0];
            //do stuff ...
            return product;
    }
}
```

Finally **`BookItemSearchAddTask`** is `ItemSearchAddTask<BookItem>`. A **`BookItem`** therefore is an `Item`, is a `Product`. The **"`I`"** is linked to the class in which this nested task class, `ItemSearchAddTask`, finds itself:

```
public abstract class ItemSearchAddWindow<I extends Item & ImageRepresentedProduct & NamedProduct> extends ViewActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {}
```

### The problem

Now, when I run this code I get the following **error**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lnet.lp.collectionista.domain.Product;
    at net.lp.collectionista.ui.activities.items.book.ItemSearchAddWindow$ItemSearchAddTask.doInBackground(ItemSearchAddWindow.java:1)
```

Note the "`[L`".

I also get compile time **warnings** at "`execute(product);`": "`Type safety: A generic array of ProductToAdd is created for a varargs parameter`"

### The cause

To my understanding, the JVM finds that in the `doInBackground` vararg it *gets a `Product[]` passed in, rather than the `Item[]` (`I[]`) it expects*. Apart from the generic arrays, which are hard to think about, I think what's going on is the case of the lion cage at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html. Not by my code, but because the **generated generic array of `ProductToAdd`** (which basically extends `Product`) was created for the varargs param.

I checked that if I pass *no argument* to `execute`, that *it works*. Also using "`execute((ProductToAdd[])new MusicCDItem[]{new MusicCDItem()});`" worked mostly (don't ask, a `MusicCDItem` is an `Item`, just like a `BookItem` is).

### A solution?

However in `start()` I can't know that I need to pass in a `BookItem`. *I only know about "`I`". Since that is a generic*, I can't create the generic array that is required to pass as the varargs param. I think what is complex about my case is the different levels of using generics, as well as the parallel hierarchies.

How do I work around this feature gap? I considered:

- **Removing generics**. A bit drastic.
- **Holding on the varargs param everywhere** in all the generics bits of code (i.e. change the method signature of `start()`), until we reach the client code, and only there do I pass one product element only, and that element is of a real type, `BookItem`. I will get the same warning there but the compiler will be able to generate the correct generic array.
- **Duplicating** the `AsyncTask` code and changing `doInBackground` to not use a varargs param because I currently may not need one. I prefer not to do this so I get the benefits when `AsyncTask` is updated in the future.
- Perhaps some **reflection** code in `start()`. Ugly.

**Is there anything shorter and more local?**

Either this, or there is some really stupid typo in my code.

Comment: Just to let you know I went with solution 2 "Holding on the varargs param everywhere" for now and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You noted that you get an "Unchecked generic array" warning in `SearchAddTask.start()` when it calls `execute()`. However, the actual warning is slightly misleading. What it says is *A generic array of ProductToAdd is created for a varargs parameter*, but what it really means is, *ProductToAdd is a type variable and at run-time I can't create an array of those, so I'll just have to use my best guess.*

If you step through into `execute()` in the debugger, you'll see that the array that was created for the `P...` declaration is a `Product[1]` -- exactly what you'd expect from the class cast exception you got. At run time, this is the best the JVM can do, because it's the closest un-erased ancestor of `ProductToAdd`.

Unfortunately, in `ItemSearchAddTask`, the JVM's also done the best it can, which is convert the `I...` declaration into an `Item[]` (the closest un-erased ancestor of `I`); thus the `ClassCastException` when `execute()` tries to call `doInBackground()`.

The least awful way I can think of offhand to get around this is to sidestep Java's type erasure by keeping `ProductToAdd`'s concrete class around at run time and creating the args array (of the correct type) yourself:

```
abstract class SearchAddTask<ProductToAdd extends Product & NamedProduct> 
  extends AddTask<ProductToAdd, ProductToAdd> {

    private final Class<ProductToAdd> productClass;

    SearchAddTask(Class<ProductToAdd> productClass) {
        this.productClass = productClass;
    }

    public void start(ViewActivity context, ProductToAdd product) {
        super.start(context, product);
        ProductToAdd[] argsArray = (ProductToAdd[]) Array.newInstance( productClass, 1 );
        argsArray[0] = product;
        execute( argsArray );
    }
}
```

It does mean you have to ensure that `BookItem.class` gets passed in, probably when you create the `AddWindow<BookItem>`, but it keeps the ugliness contained.