# Can I set compiler preferences to ignore for “A generic array is created for a varargs parameter”?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

I'm having the same problem as the person who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445233/is-it-possible-to-solve-the-a-generic-array-of-t-is-created-for-a-varargs-param).

Specifically, the warning is

> Type safety: A generic array of Object&Serializable&Comparable is
>   created for a varargs parameter

on this line of code

```
Collections.addAll(row, name, units, Boolean.FALSE);
// types: List<Object>, String, Integer, Boolean
```

The solutions posted were lovely, but I was wondering if Eclipse provides another way. Can I change the compiler preferences to ignore that sort of type safety warning? If so, which one would I change?

**EDIT:** So far, I've tried all the ones in generic types and "Inexact type match for varargs" in Potential Programming Problems." Are there warnings Eclipse won't let me ignore or is there a different one I can turn off?

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse, you can disable any warnings, and also you can enable some warnings that are disabled by default, under *Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Errors / Warnings*:

[image: Disable compilation warnings Eclipse]

Comment: Which warning would I disable?

Comment: The one you do not like. Scroll down, expand sections, the warning title should be the same or similar to the warning text.

Comment: I've already tried some, and they didn't work. Wondering if one actually exists.