# "Unchecked generic array creation for varargs parameter of type Matcher <? extends String> []" warning using CoreMatchers.allOf()

Tags: java, generics, generic-collections, hamcrest

In my UT code, extract below, I see warning :

> `Unchecked generic array creation for varargs parameter of
>
>   type  Matcher <? extends String> []`

I have read in another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445288/449347) about the problems using a generic parameter to a varargs method.

But is there a neat way to slightly restructure this test to get rid of the ugly warning and avoid `@SuppressWarnings`?

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not;

public class FooTest {


    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {

        Assert.assertThat("foo bar",
                CoreMatchers.allOf(
                containsString("foo"),
                containsString("bar"),
                not(containsString("baz"))));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If this is Java 7+, then the library you're using can annotate the method with `@SafeVarargs`. However, this is not under your control.

Otherwise there is no way to avoid an unchecked warning with this method, because the method fundamentally requires an array of a parameterized type, and it is impossible to obtain a non-`null` value of this type without an unchecked operation somewhere (either in your method or some other method that you call).

Or, looking at the documentation for `CoreMatchers`, it seems that you could consider using the alternate overload of the `allOf`, which takes an `Iterable` of matchers instead. That you can use without unchecked operations.

Comment: Note the compiler will enforce that `@SafeVarargs` is set on a **final** method, which is not possible of course on interfaces.

Comment: I used `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the test method, but now I see another compiler warning `Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. How to get rid of this?