# How to remove "unchecked generics array creation for varargs" in XYChart on JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am studying JavaFX and I am also a newbie in Java.
(I am using Java8 in Windows.)

Sample code is like below.

```
XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
eries1.setName("남자");
series1.setData(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new XYChart.Data("2015", 70),
        new XYChart.Data("2016", 40),
        new XYChart.Data("2017", 50),
        new XYChart.Data("2018", 30)
));
```

In this code, I can see a warning. That is,

```
Unchecked call to 'Data(X, Y)' as a member of raw type 'javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data'
```

Though the code works, I want to remove this warning because I am weak at Java generics programming and want to learn more about it through sample code.

What is the right way of removing that warning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the lines that look like

```
new XYChart.Data("2015", 70)
```

to specify an inferred generic type using the "diamond operator" `<>`. Like,

```
new XYChart.Data<>("2015", 70)
```

and if using an older version of Java (without the diamond operator), provide the `<X,Y>` type parameters documented in [`XYChart.Data`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html) like

```
new XYChart.Data<String, Integer>("2015", 70)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `XYChart.Series<String, Integer> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();` ? By the way, the OP did mention he was using Java 8, so the diamond operator is supported.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, I changed the code as you suggested. The warning that I wanted to remove is removed but new warning is appeared. It tells me that `FXCollections.observableArrayList` has `unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter`. What is this and how can I remove this warning? Thank you.

Comment: @Abra, I changed the code as you suggested and it tells me two warnings. `Unchecked assignment` at `FXCollections.observableArrayList` and `Unchecked call` to `Data()`.

Comment: @passion053, [Is it possible to solve the “A generic array of T is created for a varargs parameter” compiler warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445233/is-it-possible-to-solve-the-a-generic-array-of-t-is-created-for-a-varargs-param)

Answer (score 0):

The following gives **no warnings** with java 12

```
XYChart.Series<String, Integer> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Integer>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
list.add(new XYChart.Data<>("2015", 70));
list.add(new XYChart.Data<>("2016", 40));
list.add(new XYChart.Data<>("2017", 50));
list.add(new XYChart.Data<>("2018", 30));
series1.setData(list);
```

See my last comment to Elliot's answer. Basically you can't get rid of the warning (other than using the annotation `@SuppressWarning`) when using method `addAll()`.